# Base 7 Conversion with Exponents

Tags: number-theory

Explain how $56.42(4+3)^2=5642$ can be a true statement. I understand that we essentially need $(4+3)^2$ to act as $100$ in order for $56.42$ to become $5642$. However, if we operate in base $7$ and treat $4+3$ as $10$, then $100$ would not be the same result.

Please advise.

Comment: $$\left(7_{10}\right)^2=49_{10}=100_7$$

Answer (score 0):

Your entire statement is supposed to be in base $7$ and you should be careful to show that your $10$ and $100$ are also in base $7$.  The statement we are asked o prove is $56.42_7(4+3)_7^2=5642_7$  If we just write it out using the place values, we get $(5 \cdot 7 + 6 + 4\cdot 7^{-1}+2\cdot 7^{-2})\cdot 7^2=5 \cdot 7^3+6 \cdot 7^2 +4 \cdot 7 + 2$ and distributing the $7$'s in we see it is true.

Comment: I posted the question how it was posed to me. It does not necessarily have to be in base 7.

All the question asked was:
Explain how 56.42(4+3)2=5642 -- I am operating under the assumption base 7 would be the easiest way to do so. Unless you have another approach. I will be sure to make it more clear next time. Thanks.